# QMediaPlayer stuck on loading media

Tags: qt5, gstreamer, yocto, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

I want to play an audio file (tested .wav, .mp3, .flac)using QMediaPlayer from the console application on embedded iMX8 device with Yocto HardKnott system. I'm testing code from [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/audiooverview.html#playing-compressed-audio). It work's fine on PC, but it doesn't on the embedded device. It stuck with `Media Status:  QMediaPlayer::LoadingMedia` without any error. I guess that it's something in the system. Playing media from console it's possible using `aplay` command. What can be a reason? How can I fix it?

```
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, [=](qint64 position){
        qDebug()<< "Current position: " << position;
    });
    QObject::connect(player, &QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged, [=](QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status){
        qDebug()<< "Media Status: " << status;
    });
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/root/test.wav"));
    player->setVolume(100);
    player->play();
```

I tried debug Qt plugins on my platform, but I don't see any problem

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstaudiodecoder.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstaudiodecoder.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreameraudiodecode"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.audiodecode"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGstreamerAudioDecoderServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreameraudiodecode")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstcamerabin.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreamercamerabin"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.camera"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "CameraBinServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreamercamerabin")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediacapture.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediacapture.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreamermediacapture"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.audiosource"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGstreamerCaptureServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreamermediacapture")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.qt.mediaserviceproviderfactory/5.0",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "gstreamermediaplayer"
        ],
        "Services": [
            "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QGstreamerPlayerServicePlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("gstreamermediaplayer")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/platform-benchmark_app/bin/mediaservice" ...
loaded library "/usr/lib/plugins/mediaservice/libgstmediaplayer.so"
QMediaPluginLoader: loaded plugins for key "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer" : ("gstreamermediaplayer")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/plugins/resourcepolicy" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/opt/platform-benchmark_app/bin/resourcepolicy" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the system image and lack of gstreamer1.0 packets. It works separately, but it doesn't with Qt Multimedia. The solution is to add packet group **gstreamer1.0** and **gstreamer1.0-full** to fsl image recipe.

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " \
...
packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer1.0 \
packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer1.0-full \
...
"
```